# Segfault on using transform on a vector of pointers to an abstract class

Tags: c++, transform

I experience a segfault on the following code:

I have an abstract class `A` with a method

```
virtual bool Ok() const;
```

Now, I have the following vector

```
std::vector<A*> v;
```

filled with several pointers to existing child objects. I want to accumulate the results of the `Ok()` method as follows:

```
std::vector<bool> results;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), results.begin(), std::mem_fun(&A::Ok));
std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), true, std::logical_and<bool>());
```

Unfortunately, I always get a segfault on the second line, and I do not understand why. Replacing the transform call by a standard C++ loop fixes the segfault. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `results` vector is empty, and `transform` does not know that you want the results pushed onto it rather then overwriting an existing sequence.

Either initialise the `results` vector with the correct size:

```
std::vector<bool> results(v.size());
```

or use a "back insert" iterator to push the results onto the empty vector:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(results), std::mem_fun(&A::Ok));
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, my own explanation was pretty confused and wrong. You are perfectly right, of course!

Comment: I found out how to correct my own explanation. I will mark your answer as the correct one, once I can do so, of course.

Answer (score 2):

It might be stupid, but I will answer my own question directly. I found the problem shortly before clicking on "post your question" and figured that, since I typed everything already, I might also post the answer, so that someone else might benefit from it:

The answer is, that the `results` vector is empty and hence inserting at `results.begin()` is a pretty dumb thing to do. Instead, use `std::back_inserter(results)` and everything works fine!

Comment: Resizing results and using `begin()` would be alright aswell. Remember that there are a lot of things wrong with `vector<bool>`.